# Proof with a combinations

Tags: combinatorics

Prove that 
$$C^n_1 + 2\times C^n_2 + 3\times C^n_3 + \dots + n \times C^n_n = n\times 2^{n-1}$$
I tried the formula 
$$C^n_1 + C^n_2 + \dots + C^n_n = 2^n$$
Then , mutiply both sides by $$n$$
$$n\times C^n_1 + n \times C^n_2 +\dots +n\times C^n_n = n\times 2^n$$
I tried to show that the left hand side equals
 $$2(C^n_1 + 2 \times C^n_2 + \dots + n\times C^n_n )$$
To get the required but i could not get it ?

Answer (score 5):

By Newton Binomial theorem:
$$(x+1)^n=\sum_{k=0}^{n}C_{k}^n x^k,$$
so $$n(x+1)^{n-1}=\sum_{k=1}^{n}C_{k}^n k x^{k-1}.$$
Take $x=1$, you will get you equation
$$C^n_1 + 2\times C^n_2 + 3\times C^n_3 + \dots + n \times C^n_n = n\times 2^{n-1}.$$

Comment: Yes, you are right . I will edit it right now!

Answer (score 3):

Since $\binom nk=\binom n{n-k}$, we have

$$
\sum_{k=0}^nk\binom nk=\sum_{k=0}^n(n-k)\binom nk\;,
$$

and thus

$$
2\sum_{k=0}^nk\binom nk=\sum_{k=0}^nk\binom nk+\sum_{k=0}^n(n-k)\binom nk=n\sum_{k=0}^n\binom nk=n2^n\;.
$$